# How to recompile Vim?

Tags: compiling, software-sources, vim

I want to recompile Vim the exact same way Ubuntu has compiled it, but with one difference (ruby support). I have already compiled with Ruby support, but by using my own configure options, Vim --version is different in several ways from the Ubuntu version and is causing problems. If I knew how Ubuntu used ./configure I could do this.

Is there a place where I can find out how Ubuntu used ./configure for Vim while making the Ubuntu binary?

I'm guessing somewhere like http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/raring/vim/raring/files/head:/debian/ might have the answer?

Edit: this http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/raring/vim/raring/view/head:/debian/rules looks like it. Now how to use?

Edit: currently trying http://www.moosechips.com/2008/09/ubuntu-rebuild-a-source-package/

Edit: Yes, doing that worked, I'm a new "ask ubuntu" user so I can't answer my own question for 6 hours or something, otherwise I would now.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.moosechips.com/2008/09/ubuntu-rebuild-a-source-package/ as in my edits solved my problem

Comment: The link does not work any more..

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20151213150214/http://www.moosechips.com/2008/09/ubuntu-rebuild-a-source-package/ Here it is!